# How do you find percentile for the values of a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I'm given the following question and have been asked not to use numpy and pandas.

Consider the marks list of class students given in two lists

```
Students =['student1','student2','student3','student4','student5','student6','student7','student8','student9','student10'] 

Marks = [45, 78, 12, 14, 48, 43, 45, 98, 35, 80]
```

from the above two lists the `Student[0]` got `Marks[0]`, `Student[1]` got `Marks[1]` and so on.

So task is to print the name of students

- Who got top 5 ranks, in the descending order of marks
- Who got least 5 ranks, in the increasing order of marks
- Who got marks between >25th percentile <75th percentile, in the increasing order of marks.

For the first two questions, I created a dictionary of both the lists with students as keys and marks as values, I then sorted the ascending and descendingly based on the values, however, I'm getting the entire ascending and desceding list, how do I limit my top 5 results (Like LIMIT 5 in mysql lol)

Also, I'm clueless on how to tackle the 3rd question, can you please help me ?

Please find my code below

```
Students=['student1','student2','student3','student4','student5','student6','student7','student8','student9','student10']

Marks = [45, 78, 12, 14, 48, 43, 47, 98, 35, 80]

def display_dash_board(students, marks):

    dictionary = dict(zip(Students,Marks))

    print('top_5_students')

    for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True):
          print("%s: %s" % (key, value))

#this is giving me the entire descending list (not python list) of all 10 students how to limit to five?


    print('least_5_students')

    for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
          print("%s: %s" % (key, value))

    #this is giving me the entire ascending list (not python list) of all 10 students how to limit to five?   

    # How to go about the percentile question ?

display_dash_board(Students, Marks)
```

Comment: How do you want to handle in case of tie in `Marks`?

Comment: I think your code have error like `dictionary = dict(zip(Students,Marks))` is defined in the function but used outside the function in `sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit to five, add `[:5]` to only interate over the first 5 elements of your `sorted` list.

`for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)[:5]:` should do the work for the descending list.

About the percentile stuff, this is more a statistic question but you can do :

```
n = len(marks)
first_quartile = int(n/4) if (n/4).is_integer() else int(n/4) + 1
third_quartile = int(3*n/4) # as we want <75th percentile
```

And then you display the value of sorted `(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])` between these 2 values:

`sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])[first_quartile:third_quartile]`

Answer (score 1):

```
def percentile(N, percent, key=lambda x:x):
    """
    Find the percentile of a list of values.

    @parameter N - is a list of values. Note N MUST BE already sorted.
    @parameter percent - a float value from 0.0 to 1.0.
    @parameter key - optional key function to compute value from each element of N.

    @return - the percentile of the values
    """
    if not N:
        return None
    k = (len(N)-1) * percent
    f = math.floor(k)
    c = math.ceil(k)
    if f == c:
        return key(N[int(k)])
    d0 = key(N[int(f)]) * (c-k)
    d1 = key(N[int(c)]) * (k-f)
    return d0+d1
```

use the above function to calculate the value for percentile by providing the sorted list of marks. Then filter the dictionary based on the percentile value.

The above function is inspired from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511478-finding-the-percentile-of-the-values/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without using numpy just similar to your code.

```
for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
      percentage = value * 100.0 / 100  # I assumed 100 as total marks (You can change it if you want like sum(Marks))
      if 25 < percentage < 75 :
            print("%s: %s : %d" % (key, value, percentage))
```

Output

```
student9: 35 : 35
student6: 43 : 43
student1: 45 : 45
student7: 47 : 47
student5: 48 : 48
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete answer to the question

```
Students=['student1','student2','student3','student4','student5','student6','student7','student8','student9','student10'] 
Marks = [45, 78, 12, 14, 48, 43, 47, 98, 35, 80]

dictionary = dict(zip(Students,Marks)) ### to map students and marks 
for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)[0:5]:
    print("%s: %s" % (key, value))

for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(),key = lambda item: item[1])[0:5]:
      print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
    
for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
      percentage = value * 100.0 / 100  # I assumed 100 as total marks (You can change it if you want like sum(Marks))
      if 25 < percentage < 75 :
            print("%s: %d" % (key, value))
```

Comment: Also, [Hava a look here to [how to indent your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300124/13903942)